# please how do i resolve this issue with xampp

Tags: xampp

Warning: "continue 2" targeting switch is equivalent to "break 2". Did you mean to use "continue 3"? in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\revslider\includes\operations.class.php on line 2858

Answer (score 1):

Open operations.class.php with a text editor, go to line 2858 and rename **continue 2** to **break 2**. When done, your code should resemble the one below
`if(!isset($layer['video_data']->id) || empty($layer['video_data']->id)) break 2;`